# How to authenticate google service account credentials

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, cloud, client

I have a google service account private key (json format) from google console.
How do I create a new client in golang (what google api do I use) and authenticate the credentials I got without setting environment variable?
I would like to provide the Google service account credentials manually in Golang.
I started by passing the json file as byte array:
`creds, err := google.CredentialsFromJSON(ctx, blob)`. Blob is the byte array of the json file.
I can create a client successfully with cloud.google.com/go/secretmanager/apiv1 even after I changed the private key (ouch). So I wonder at what point and how do I authenticate the creds?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use your credential?

Answer (score 1):

Question is unclear. I allow myself to rephrase it a "**How do you create a valid credential from a service account's keyfile?**"
Well, Google indeed implement a [strategy](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) to give an authenticated indentity to the calling process.
At a coarse grain, it indeed look for an environment variable definition called GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL which value contains a path to a valid SA keyfile. Otherwise it uses the default service account from the piece of compute it runs from (GCE, GKE pod, Appengine, cloud function,...).
Finally you've got an error otherwise.

Working locally, a good practice to set this default credential is to use the cloud SDK with command [`gcloud auth application-default login`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login). That way the application would act on the behalf of the logged person (you for instance and consume with your permissions and quotas).
Otherwise you could set up the env var manually to point to the service account's keyfile you downloaded.

Now if you run outside from a google cloud environment you can manually build credential unsing a keyfile like you do. The following [example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/go) is explicit. **What you must understand is that the credential you forge is an argument to any Google API client constructor.**
Once the API client is built with your credential, you just consume it by calling the methods it exposes. Authentication happens under the hood. Every call to Google API is authenticated with an OAuth2 token which retrieving flow is described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#serviceaccount).
You could dig into the source code client of the client API if you need to be convinced, but the nice thing is you don't have to.

Comment: Thank you @chaiyachaiya for your detailed reply. The case is: My user download service account private key in a json format from google console. Then the user opens the json file, copy the content to the UI and submit (post it as part of a body ins a post request). The back-end unmarshal it, and gets the content. Now, before accessing gcp with this information, I want to validate the content of the json, just in case the user has entered wrong info in the UI.   Next:

Comment: I changed the private key in the UI and tried the following:                                                                ```creds, err := google.CredentialsFromJSON(ctx, blob, secretmanager.DefaultAuthScopes()...)``` and             
 ```_, err = secretmanager.NewClient(ctx, option.WithCredentials(creds))```.                                 
 Did not get any authentication error. You said that authentication is done under the hood, so what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Also, read aobut the JWT. Should'nt I use this:     https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication ?  Thank you again for your time!!

Comment: What would be the usecase? the user you provide the keyfile with is a partner of your who need to access some of your google service (GCS for instance, or a cloud endpoint API)? Or do you need this file to let the user consume a public Google API (Gmail for instance). None of  these case should implie a copy/paste of the content of the keyfile in a form. I will detail according your answer to those questions. The link you point to is indeed the two legs Oauth2 process but you don't need to take care of it. Google clients does. (e.g: when calling client.CreateSecret(ctx, createSecretReq))

Comment: check this: https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries

Comment: I created a service which creates a projectclaim resource which will trigger creation of a project. This projectclaim needs to have a reference to a secret which is built on the json info I get from anybody who wants to have a project. I do not want to store the json in env var. This is the reason I create the secret manually with the content of the secret key and create the project claim with that secret. Also, in order to get the secret key, I ask my client to send it through the UI and  not as a file. But it does not matter, since the content of it can be changed even by mistake.

Comment: So Beofre I create the projectclaim I wanted to verify that the secret key was not changed (intentionally or not). So I was thinking of creating a client with the creds and authenticate the creds

Comment: If I remember well you can't create a Credential with a corrupted Json file. So trying to create one like you do with a wrong content will trigger an error.

 
Your usecase description is unclear to me. Your service create what kind of project? GCP ones? Also, why would a user generate a keyfile to be able to use your service. A classic Oauth2 authentication is not enough in your case ?